# How do I make my JavaScript email a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email

I am currently working on a 'contact form', I have been working on this for quite a while but, I just can't figure out how to make JavaScript email the form to my email adress.

This is my code :

```
    <form id="myform" action="mailto:contact@anika.nl">

<label for="FirstName">Name:</label>
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" />

<label for="EMail">Email:</label>
<input id="EMail" name="EMail" type="text" />

<label for="Message">Message:</label>
<textarea id="Message" cols="20" name="Address" rows="5"></textarea>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var frmvalidator = new Validator("myform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","req","Please enter your First Name");
frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","maxlen=20", "Max length for FirstName is 20");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","maxlen=50");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","req");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","email");
// ]]></script>
```

Does someone see what I'm doing wrong/what's missing?

Comment: Javascript is not mailing this form, the submit button and the client's hopefully correctly configured mail client is. If you wonder why the JavaScript does not VALIDATE then it is likely you did not include the validator.js? Also never call anything _name="submit"_ in a form if you even want to submit it using script. Please let us know what validator you are using. Is it [this one](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) ? Then you need `<script src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the head of the page after downloading it.

Comment: yes, I am jusing 'gen_validatorv4.js'